# Best practice for uploading vidoes into s3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, image-uploading

What is the best practice for uploading images and videos into S3 buckets. In my use case users can upload their vidoes and images and I have to store those images and videos in effective way into S3 bucket (without data loss). I read some related posts but I could not find out the better solution. I am using **React JS** and I have to upload it from React JS code. And each video's size would be more than 200 MB. So I am worrying about how to send those videos into S3 bucket in very less time and effective way. Please anyone suggest me a good approach to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

S3 will not lose your data. If you receive a 200 response from S3, you can be confident there will be no data lost.

As for best practices, you should use [`PUT Object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) for files that are smaller than 5 GB. You can also use [`POST Object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html) to allow your users to [upload files directly from the browser](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/articles/browser-uploads-to-s3-using-html-post-forms/). The 5 GB size limit still applies in the case of `POST Object`.

Once you reach the 5 GB limit, your only choice is use S3's [multipart upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html). Using the multipart upload API, you can upload files of to 5 TB in size.

Comment: Thanks spg. But I am looking at how to send those videos into S3 bucket from my web application. The videos size should not be very high like each video should be around 200 MB.

Comment: You should definitely look into using POST Object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html